# How could I convert a list of Struct * to a list of void *?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having this std::map :

```
std::map<int, std::list<void *>>
```

And I want to put this list in it :

```
  std::list<Part *>     _player;
```

Problem is, when I do the asignation

```
  this->_entities[0] = &this->_player;
```

I got this error

```
no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::map<int, std::__cxx11::list<void*> >::mapped_type {aka std::__cxx11::list<void*>}’ and ‘std::__cxx11::list<Part*>*’)
```

So I guess I need to cast it, but how ?

Comment: You are taking the address of your `_player`. i.e. you are trying to assign a "pointer-to-(list-of-Part-pointer)" to a "list-of-void-pointer", which obviously does not make sense.  Are you trying to do `_entities[0] = _player;` instead?

Comment: You are right, dunno why I did this .. but still don't work, i still have the error with no match for operator =

Comment: of course it does not work :)  just trying to guide you closer to the conclusion.  There is a reasonable answer though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this in my utils, actually works, just recast the whole list:

```
template<class T, class I>
vector<T> castVector(const vector<I> v) /**< Cast a uint64* vector to any other type, returns a newly builded vector*/
{
    vector<T> ret(v.size());
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), ret.begin(), [](I p){return (T)(p);});
    return ret;
}
```

You can use this:

```
this->_entities[0] = retypeVector<void*, Part*>(_player);
```